# His memory is as immortal as his arts have made me. (grammar)

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> All the world has heard of Cornelius Agrippa. ***His memory is as immortal as his arts have made me.*** All the world has also heard of his scholar, who, unawares, raised the foul fiend during his master's absence, and was destroyed by him.

From *Mortal Immortal* by Mary Shelley.

Is the highlighted sentence grammatically correct?

As far as I can tell, *His memory* corresponds to *his arts*, not to *his arts have made me*. I mean, the correspondence has to be 'word to word' or 'phrase to phrase'. Or maybe the sentence needs a relative pronoun or something?

In fact, what does this sentence mean exactly?

Comment: The parallelism in this sentence isn't perfect, but that does not make the sentence ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a likening of the degree of immortality possessed by *his memory* to the degree of immortality conferred upon *me* by *his arts*:

> His memory is immortal in some degree.
> His arts have made me immortal in the same degree.
>
> His arts have made me as immortal as his memory ... *mutatis mutandis*, then
> His memory is as immortal as his arts have made me.